# update in mysql php pdo not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update my DB, using the update statement in MySQL PHP PDO. However, it returns me the error:

**SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens**

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

My code is:

```
$sqlupd = "UPDATE 'vendorprof'
    SET 'vd_loc_add1' = :Add1,
    'vd_loc_add2' = :Add2,
    'vd_loc_city' = :City,
    'vd_loc_state' = :State,
    'vd_cont_per' = :ContPerson,
    'vd_cont_mob' = :Mobile,
    WHERE 'vd_user_id' = :userid2";

$profileupd = $conn->prepare($sqlupd);
$profileupd->bindParam(":Add1",$Add1);
$profileupd->bindParam(":Add2",$Add2);
$profileupd->bindParam(":City",$City);
$profileupd->bindParam(":State",$State);
$profileupd->bindParam(":ContPerson",$ContPerson);
$profileupd->bindParam(":Mobile",$Mobile);

$profileupd->execute();
echo $profileupd->rowCount()."records updated Successfully";
```

Comment: 7 placeholders and 6 bounded parameters? 7 != 6

Comment: You forgot to bind :userid2 as well

Comment: and .... the Colon at he end of line must be removed ** 'vd_cont_mob' = :Mobile,**

Comment: @hasumedic..... Got it .. Thanks :)

Comment: @BerndBuffen.... Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously you declare 7 parameter markers, but bind only 6. You are 1 parameter marker short.

```
:Add1 // is bound as $Add1
:Add2 // is bound as $Add2
:City // is bound as $City
:State // is bound as $State
:ContPerson // is bound as $ContPerson
:Mobile // is bound as $Mobile
:userid2 // is bound ... not
```

Moreover, your query is wrong. You do not wrap column names around with quotes. Plus, you did put a comma before `WHERE`... It has to be:

```
$sqlupd = "UPDATE vendorprof
    SET vd_loc_add1 = :Add1,
    vd_loc_add2 = :Add2,
    vd_loc_city = :City,
    vd_loc_state = :State,
    vd_cont_per = :ContPerson,
    vd_cont_mob = :Mobile
    WHERE vd_user_id = :userid2";
```

Comment: @AnamikAdhikary just a piece of advice. Judging by your profile, you do not accept answers on your questions. Please do so, it might help future readers

Comment: Sure... I will do that!
One more issue popped up.. Now that I have bound the userid2, I get this new error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''vendorprof' SET 'vd_loc_add1' =' at line 1